# How can I use a Do loop (or something else) to automate this? SAS

Tags: loops, sas, do-loops

```
proc sql;

create table MMx
as select distinct a.*, b.max_days_late as max_LD_1, 
    case 
        when b.max_days_late ^=. then b.max_days_late
        when b.max_days_late =. then 0
end as  Ld
from output.sample_y_n_deln a
left join work.sample_y_n_deln b
    on a.contract=b.contract and a.delnum+1=b.delnum

;quit;
```

So I want to repeat this but with max _ld_2, max_ld_3 etc

and delnum+2 the original delnum or +1 the max_ld_1 delnum, so n+1 times where I want it to end at n=12. I'm new to SAS and I'm not sure how a do loop fits in to an sql step or if I need to make this a data step and then loop it.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWJCD.jpg

What I want is a simple loop that can do n+1 iterations of this logic.

```
  proc sql;

    create table MMx
    as select distinct a.*, b.max_days_late as max_LD_2, 
    case 
        when b.max_days_late ^=. then b.max_days_late
       /*       when b.max_days_late =. then 0*/
end as  Ld
from work.MMx a
left join work.MMx b
    on a.contract=b.contract and a.delnum+2=b.delnum

;quit;

     proc sql;

     create table MMx
     as select distinct a.*, b.max_days_late as max_LD_3, 
    case 
        when b.max_days_late ^=. then b.max_days_late
     /*     when b.max_days_late =. then 0*/
     end as  Ld
     from work.MMx a
     left join work.MMx b
    on a.contract=b.contract and a.delnum+3=b.delnum

      ;quit;

     proc sql;
     
     create table MMx
     as select distinct a.*, b.max_days_late as max_LD_4, 
    case 
        when b.max_days_late ^=. then b.max_days_late
     /*     when b.max_days_late =. then 0*/
          end as  Ld
     from work.MMx a
     left join work.MMx b
    on a.contract=b.contract and a.delnum+4=b.delnum

     ;quit;

     proc sql;

     create table MMx
     as select distinct a.*, b.max_days_late as max_LD_5, 
    case 
        when b.max_days_late ^=. then b.max_days_late
     /*     when b.max_days_late =. then 0*/
     end as  Ld
     from work.MMx a
     left join work.MMx b
    on a.contract=b.contract and a.delnum+5=b.delnum

     ;quit;

     proc sql;

     create table MMx
     as select distinct a.*, b.max_days_late as max_LD_6, 
    case 
        when b.max_days_late ^=. then b.max_days_late
     /*     when b.max_days_late =. then 0*/
     end as  Ld
     from work.MMx a
     left join work.MMx b
    on a.contract=b.contract and a.delnum+6=b.delnum

     ;quit;

     proc sql;

     create table MMx
     as select distinct a.*, b.max_days_late as max_LD_7, 
    case 
        when b.max_days_late ^=. then b.max_days_late
     /*     when b.max_days_late =. then 0*/
     end as  Ld
     from work.MMx a
     left join work.MMx b
    on a.contract=b.contract and a.delnum+7=b.delnum

     ;quit;

     proc sql;

     create table MMx
     as select distinct a.*, b.max_days_late as max_LD_8, 
    case 
        when b.max_days_late ^=. then b.max_days_late
     /*     when b.max_days_late =. then 0*/
     end as  Ld
     from work.MMx a
     left join work.MMx b
    on a.contract=b.contract and a.delnum+8=b.delnum

     ;quit;

     proc sql;

     create table MMx
     as select distinct a.*, b.max_days_late as max_LD_9, 
    case 
        when b.max_days_late ^=. then b.max_days_late
     /*     when b.max_days_late =. then 0*/
     end as  Ld
     from work.MMx a
     left join work.MMx b
    on a.contract=b.contract and a.delnum+9=b.delnum

     ;quit;

     proc sql;

     create table MMx
     as select distinct a.*, b.max_days_late as max_LD_10, 
    case 
        when b.max_days_late ^=. then b.max_days_late
     /*     when b.max_days_late =. then 0*/
     end as  Ld
     from work.MMx a
     left join work.MMx b
    on a.contract=b.contract and a.delnum+10=b.delnum

     ;quit;
     proc sql;

     create table MMx
     as select distinct a.*, b.max_days_late as max_LD_11, 
    case 
        when b.max_days_late ^=. then b.max_days_late
     /*     when b.max_days_late =. then 0*/
     end as  Ld
     from work.MMx a
     left join work.MMx b
    on a.contract=b.contract and a.delnum+11=b.delnum

     ;quit;

     proc sql;

     create table MMx
     as select distinct a.*, b.max_days_late as max_LD_12, 
    case 
        when b.max_days_late ^=. then b.max_days_late
     /*     when b.max_days_late =. then 0*/
     end as  Ld
     from work.MMx a
     left join work.MMx b
    on a.contract=b.contract and a.delnum+12=b.delnum

     ;quit;
```

but with a column names as max_ld_1, max_ld_2 etc.

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to do.  What is the meaning of MAX_LD_1, MAX_LD_2 etc.  What do your input datasets look like?  What output do you want to create?

Comment: Show how you'd do it for a second iteration.

Comment: 12 indicates to me 12 months.  Is it possible you are doing a 12 month rolling computation ?  You might want to perform the compuation 'vertically' and then transpose or tabulate reporting, or use an array possibly with indices computed in modulus.  Make the question better by showing sample data and expected output.

Comment: @Tom @ Richard . Max_Ld_1, Max_ld_2 are integer values for the nth next month. I want to add them as rows for each contract so I have 12 time periods in rows for each contract date.

Comment: @Richard I tried transposing but then subsequent merger is tricky because you can't merge on contract names alone. And transposing the data one by one is even more tiresome.

Comment: Don't post data as photographs.  Just copy and paste the actual text. Or just retype the 10 to 20 numbers in your photograph as text.